# not get location using Plugin.Geolocator in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I want to do a simple app that brings me my current location, I am using Geolocator plug in to consult my location but it throw me an exception error when i call the method GetPositionAsync(), the app have permission to access location in my phone. there is my code:

```
  try
        {

            if ( locator.IsGeolocationEnabled == false )
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "location is not enable", "aceptar");
                return;
            }
            if( locator.IsGeolocationAvailable == false)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "location is not aviable", "aceptar");
                return;
            }

            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.MaxValue);
            GeoPos = position.Latitude.ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "aceptar");
        }
```

its send me to a catch exception and display this error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T2gw.png)

thanks to all for your help!

Comment: if a change to var position = await locator.GetLastKnownLocationAsync(); works but is fine do ti that way??

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable place that an index out of range exception can occur is in some external code, as far as I can tell.

Maybe the assignment to `GeoPos` has an exception causing effect...

Comment: even if I comment // GeoPos = position.Latitude.ToString(); still throw  the exception